# Which stage of an Android activity life cycle is ideal to store data?

Tags: android

I read that onPause() is the first indication that the user is leaving your activity and this is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session. But some posts say that CPU intensive computations should not be done in onPause() in order to allow for a speedy transition to user's next destination. 
Now if I want to store user entered data in database, where should I perform this operation - onStop() or onPause()? I think it should be in onStop(), as it is CPU intensive computation, but if onStop() doesn't get called then I will lose the user inputs. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On stop() will be called.  If you need to do a lot of "CPU intensive computation".  You should keep it in a background thread to

Comment: Like @Jasz said: Use a background thread. But nowadays smartphones are really fast and if you dont have "huge" data to save in your database just do it in the main thread. I would not recommend to override any lifecycle methods if it is not really necassary!!! if you do however, e.g. onStop() you have to override super.onStop()